# AngularJS: How to add a class on element when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that this question has some answers but I can't find a solution for my code structure...

I want to add class `isVisible` or `notVisible` when I click on `toggle-class`

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yep8mwbx/5/)

This is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-class" ng-click="element = !element">Click to toggle menu</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-class="{isVisible: element, notVisible: !element}">
    Add class
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your visible and not visible class?

Comment: pls add your CSS and js in the question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ear1mko0/1/ -just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.isVisible{
   display:none;
  }

.notVisible{
     display:show;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <a href="#" class="toggle-class" ng-click="element = !element">Click to toggle menu</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div ng-class="{'isVisible': element, 'notVisible': !element}">
    Add class
  </div>  
</div>
```

try this

```
  <div ng-class="{'isVisible': element, 'notVisible': !element}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to be okay except one statment

```
     <div ng-class="{'isVisible': element, 'notVisible': !element}">
```

this must be your statment

and define **isVisible** and  **notVisible** class

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<div ng-class="{'isVisible': element, 'notVisible': !element}">Add class</div>

.isVisible{color:red;}
.notVisible{ color:green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have update your [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yep8mwbx/9/)

```
<div ng-app ng-init="element= true">

        <a href="#" class="toggle-class" ng-click="element = !element">Click to toggle menu
        </a>
  <div ng-class="{'isVisible': element, 'notVisible': !element}">
    Add class
    </div>  
</div>
```